# Gradient Layer Is Not Working on Portrait Mode in Xib File

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

i wants to set gradient layer on a `UIView` in `Xib` File but in Portrait Mode Gradient Layer it's not fill all Of `UIView`.

Gradient Class :

```
extension UIView {
    @discardableResult
    func applyGradient(colours: [UIColor]) -> CAGradientLayer {
        return self.applyGradient(colours: colours, locations: nil)
    }

    @discardableResult
    func applyGradient(colours: [UIColor], locations: [NSNumber]?) -> CAGradientLayer {
        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.colors = colours.map { $0.cgColor }
        gradient.locations = locations
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
        return gradient
    }
}
```

`Xib` File Class :

```
class TempView: UIView {

  override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
}

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews();
        self.viewMain.applyGradient(colours: [.black, .gray])
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using this tempview in storyboard? and what is viewMain? Describe your code.

Comment: tempView is Class of Xib File and viewMain is a UIView in in Xib File

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    class TempView: UIView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
     }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews();
        self.viewMain.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.viewMain.applyGradient(colours: [.black, .gray])
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this extension To solve This Problem :

```
extension UIView {

    func addGradient(colors: [UIColor], locations: [NSNumber]) {
        addSubview(ViewWithGradient(addTo: self, colors: colors, locations: locations))
    }
}

class ViewWithGradient: UIView {

    private var gradient = CAGradientLayer()

    init(addTo parentView: UIView, colors: [UIColor], locations: [NSNumber]){

        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 2))
        restorationIdentifier = "__ViewWithGradient"

        for subView in parentView.subviews {
            if let subView = subView as? ViewWithGradient {
                if subView.restorationIdentifier == restorationIdentifier {
                    subView.removeFromSuperview()
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        let cgColors = colors.map { (color) -> CGColor in
            return color.cgColor
        }

        gradient.frame = parentView.frame
        gradient.colors = cgColors
        gradient.locations = locations
        backgroundColor = .clear

        parentView.addSubview(self)
        parentView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
        parentView.backgroundColor = .clear
        autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        clipsToBounds = true
        parentView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if let parentView = superview {
            gradient.frame = parentView.bounds
        }
    }

    override func removeFromSuperview() {
        super.removeFromSuperview()
        gradient.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
}
```